# IntelliJ + Kotlin + Gradle: How can I correct this error "Language version 1.5 is experimental"?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a project that is using Kotlin 1.5 with Gradle 7 and IntelliJ 2021.1.1.  The project was originally based on Kotlin 1.4 and was recently upgraded to 1.5.

When I build the project, I see the following warning, which seems to be related to the compileTestKotlin Gradle task.  There are no warnings for non-test compiles.  I have scoured through IntelliJ settings, Gradle configuration files, but to no avail.  I'd appreciate any help to resolve this warning...  Thank you for any help!

> Task :services:track:compileTestKotlin
> w: Language version 1.5 is experimental, there are no backwards compatibility guarantees for new language and library features

Here are my compiler settings in Gradle:

```
tasks {
    withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            //allWarningsAsErrors = true // best practice
            apiVersion = "1.5"
            freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "11"
            languageVersion = "1.5"
        }
    }

    withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinCompile<*>> {
        kotlinOptions {
            //allWarningsAsErrors = true // best practice
            apiVersion = "1.5"
            languageVersion = "1.5"
        }
    }
}
```

IntelliJ Kotlin Configuration
[image: IntelliJ Kotlin Configuration]

The issue has been corrected.  The buildSrc folder contained a build.gradle.kts file that had Kotlin 1.4 dependencies.  I've changed them to 1.5, and the project builds properly.
[image: Kotlin Version Changes]

Comment: Have you upgraded your gradle kotlin plugin? `plugins { kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.0" }`?

Comment: It really looks like you're compiling the project with Kotlin compiler 1.4 and experimental to it language version 1.5. Try to switch compiler to 1.5.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I've added two images of the Kotlin configuration in IntelliJ.  The settings look reasonable, I think..

Comment: I worked my way through the Gradle build configuration and discovered the issue that both of you mentioned...  The build.gradle.kts file in my buildSrc folder was using the 1.4.31 dependency! Argggg!  I've corrected it and the issue has been resolved.  Thank you for the nudge in the correct direction, gentlemen!  I've posted the change, above.